# Why doesn't $p(R|G) > p (R|¬G)$ imply $p(¬R|¬G) > p(R|¬G)$?

Tags: probability

I think that $p(R|G) > p (R|¬G)$ is not enough to conclude anything about the relationship between $p(¬R|¬G)$ and $p(R|¬G),$ but I can't see clearly why. Could someone please provide a proof that $$p(R|G) > p (R|¬G)$$ doesn't imply $$p(¬R|¬G) > p(R|¬G)?$$

Comment: It's more likely to rain today than it is to rain tomorrow.  Is it necessary that the chance of rain tomorrow is less than 50%?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a counterexample where  $$p(R|G) > p (R|¬G),$$ yet $$p(¬R|¬G) < p(R|¬G).$$

[image]

Comment: @AndreasBlass Yes, thanks; fixed.